# COM Port already open in Windows 7

Tags: delphi, serial-port, port

When I try to connect to the COM port on Windows 7, using AsyncPro (TApdComPort), I'm getting the error message like "Device already open". But the same application working fine in Win Xp machine. I'm used Delphi 6 to develop the program. Please help me to resolve this issue. 
Appreciate your help.
Thanks.

Comment: So what's the problem? The error message tells you what's wrong. What reason have you to believe the problem isn't just as simple as finding the program that has the port open and closing it? See [Now who's using my COM port?](http://superuser.com/q/55334) on Super User. Stack Overflow is for programming problems, but I'm not yet convinced you actually *have* a programming problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What component are you using to connect to the COM Port?

If you are using CreateFile API to open the port use GetLastError() API for a detalied error of your problem.

If that doesn't help you it means it's a hardware problem

Don't know about the component you are using ApdComPort but you could do a simple test write a simple application to open the port just like this

```
var
  comHandle : THandle;
begin
  comHandle := CreateFile('COM66',GENERIC_READ or GENERIC_WRITE,0,nil,OPEN_EXISTING,0,0);
  if comHandle = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then ShowMessage(SysErrorMessage(GetLastError))
  else ShowMessage('Port opened');
end //Make shure to replace COM66 with your actual COM Port you wish to open
```

If it shows Port opened then it's a problem with the component you are using so i would recommend this one http://sourceforge.net/projects/comport/ post here other error message to  find a solution.

Comment: @opc0de I'm using the component ApdComPort. Please let me know if you need more information

Comment: @Delphian checkout my edit and post what error you are getting

Comment: I'm using the following settings,ComNumber := 1;
              Baud := 1200;
              DataBits := 8;
              StopBits := 2;
              Parity := pNone

Comment: @Delphian the com port should be opened regardless of the baudrate etc so settings are not interesting here.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem which was solved by changing the port name from COM1 to COM4 in the serial port advanced properties (via the device manager).

Everything then worked fine. Some programs still see the renamed port as COM1, but now they can access the port.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was remote desktop. I unchecked all the local Resources in the Connection. Somehow remote desktop was blocking the com port!